# Plexum install gives error C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Tags: php, fastcgi, iis-8

I have configured **PHP with Fast CGI module with IIS.**
 When I install **plexum software** (by run plexum_setup.php file) It gives error like

**C:\php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly**

When I run phpinfo.php then it run successfully.

Version info >

PHP Non thread safety version 5.6.25,   Server IIS,  Zend loader supported version

**Tried solutions >**

I installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 but still no success.

Created new application pool with "Classic" pipeline mode and "No Managed Code" and enabled 32 bit true but same issue still exists.

Anyone have any idea please tell us.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a big R & D, I have found that there are permission issues that are not working with Windows server. SO I have set up all required software for **Plexum** on **Linux server** and then Plexum installed successfully.

**Plexum support Linux server well.**

Thanks